# How to add option for booking? In booking there should be option to **input, delete , add**. Every booking should have client name, num of booking

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So, option booking should have options for  input, add,delete, Every booking should have: **client username, arrangement, num of booking places and is it payed or not.**

```
# options for torustic agency application
options = input('Destinations,\n Arrangements,\n Booking,Search,\n Statistic,\n Enter option:  ')
print()
# available destinations
destinations =['Brazil','Cuba','Mexico']

# every destination has information about itself
Brazil = ['Brasilia','South America']
Cuba = ['Havana','South America']
Mexico = ['Mexico City, South America']

# empty list for appending and deleting destinations
arr= []

# infinite loop
while True:
    if options == 'Destinations':
        x = input('Select: ')
        if x == 'show_all': # show all destination
            print(destinations)
        elif x == 'del': # delete destination
            y = input('Enter what to remove: ')
            destinations.remove(y)
        elif x == 'add': # add destination
            z = input('What country to add: ')
            destinations.append(z)
        if x == 'Brazil': # show destinations info
            print(Brazil)
        elif x == 'Cuba':
            print(Cuba)
        elif x == 'Mexico':
            print(Mexico)
    
    if options == 'Arrangements':
        

        x = input("Select arrangement : ")
        if x == 'Brazil': # shows arrangement for Brazil 
            print('destination: Brasilia,\nprice: 1000$\nfrom 2022:05:12 to 2022:05:25   ') 
            print()
        elif x == 'Mexico':
            print('destination: Mexico City,\nprice: 1000$\nfrom 2022:05:12 to 2022:05:25   ')
            print()
        elif x == 'Cuba':
            print('destination: Havana,\nprice: 1000$\nfrom 2022:05:12 to 2022:05:25   ')
            print()
        elif x == 'add': # add arrangement in an empty list
            x = input('select arrrangement: ')
            arr.append(x)
            print(arr) 
        elif  x =='del': # delete arragnement
            x = input('Delete : ')
            arr.remove(x)
            print(arr)
```

Also program should have options for search and statistics. Search activates menu with bookings. for Search input needs user name of client and booking date from start to end.

For Statistics shows total data of system , all arrangements, all destinations, all num of bookings , number of not used arrangements, sum of payed arrangements, total depth of not payed arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not a simple problem. For example, how are destinations, arrangements and bookings related. There's probably many way to solve your problem but the domain is not well defined for us to give you an helpful answer.

There's no easy solution to your problem. So here's a complex solution that may be on way to tackle your problem:

```py
def print_title(title):
    line = '-' * len(title)
    print(f'\n{title}\n{line}')

def check_if_empty(menu_options_to_check, message_if_empty):
    def outside_decorator(function):
        def inside_decorator():
            if menu_options_to_check:
                function()
            else:
                print(message_if_empty)
        return inside_decorator
    return outside_decorator

def display_menu(title, menu_options, message_if_empty, exit_option="Return to previous menu", give_choice=False):
    def outside_decorator(function):
        @check_if_empty(menu_options, message_if_empty)
        def inside_decorator():
            finished_choosing = False
            while not finished_choosing:
                options = list(menu_options)
                option_chosen = -1
                while not (0 <= option_chosen <= len(options)):
                    print_title(title)
                    menu = '\n'.join(
                        f'{number}) {option}' 
                        for (number, option) 
                        in enumerate(options, start=1)
                    )
                    print(menu, f'\n\n0) {exit_option}\n')
                    request_sentence =  'Please choose the number of the option desired: '
                    option_chosen = int(input(request_sentence))

                    if not (0 <= option_chosen <= len(options)):
                        print('Please choose one of the options in the menu\nTry again\n')
                print()

                if not (finished_choosing := (option_chosen == 0)):
                    value_to_transmit = option_chosen - 1 if give_choice else options[option_chosen - 1]
                    function(value_to_transmit)
        return inside_decorator
    return outside_decorator

destinations = {
    'Brazil' : {
        'Capital': 'Brasilia',
        'Continent': 'South America',
        'Price': 1000,
        'Dates': ['2022-05-12', '2022-05-25'],
    },
    'Cuba' : {
        'Capital': 'Havana',
        'Continent': 'South America',
        'Price': 1000,
        'Dates': ['2022-05-12', '2022-05-25'],
    },
    'Mexico' : {
        'Capital': 'Mexico City',
        'Continent': 'South America',
        'Price': 1000,
        'Dates': ['2022-05-12', '2022-05-25']
    },
}

arrangements = []

options_main_menu = [
    'Destinations',
    'Arrangements',
    #'Booking', 
    #'Search',
    #'Statistics',
]

@display_menu('Main menu', options_main_menu, 'No options available for this menu', exit_option="Quit the application", give_choice=True)
def main_menu_manager(option_chosen):

    options_destinations = (
        'Show all destinations',
        'Add (or replace) a destination',
        'Delete a destination',
        'Show info about a specific destination'
    )

    @display_menu('Destination menu', options_destinations, 'No options available for this menu', give_choice=True)
    def destinations_menu_manager(option_chosen):
        @check_if_empty(destinations,'No destination is defined in the system')
        def show_all():
            print_title('All destinations:')
            print('\n'.join(destinations))

        def add():
            print_title('Add (or replace) a destination')
            country = input('Which country? ')
            capital = input('Its capital? ')
            continent = input('Its continent? ')
            price = input('Price of its arrangement? ')
            from_date = input('Date of the beginning of the arrangement? ')
            to_date = input('Date of the end of the arrangement? ')

            destinations[country] = {
                'Capital': capital,
                'Continent': continent,
                'Price' : price,
                'Dates': [from_date, to_date]
            }

        @display_menu('Select the destination to delete', destinations, 'No destination is defined in the system')
        def delete(country):
            del destinations[country]
            print(f'{country} deleted')

        @display_menu('Select the destination to detail', destinations, 'No destination is defined in the system')
        def show_specific(country):
            print(
    f'''Country: {country} 
    Capital: {destinations[country]['Capital']}
    Continent: {destinations[country]['Continent']}'''
            )

        actions = (
            show_all,
            add,
            delete,
            show_specific
        )
        
        actions[option_chosen]()

    options_arrangements = (
        'Show arrangement for a country',
        'Show current arrangement list',
        'Add arrangement to current arrangement list',
        'Delete arrangement in current arrangement list'
    )

    @display_menu('Arrangement menu', options_arrangements, 'No options available for this menu', give_choice=True)
    def arrangement_menu_manager(option_chosen):
        @display_menu('Select which destination you want to display its arrangement', destinations, 'No arrangement has been defined in the system')
        def show_country(country):
            print(
    f'''Destination: {country}
        Price: {destinations[country]['Price']}
        From: {destinations[country]['Dates'][0]} to {destinations[country]['Dates'][1]}'''
            )
    
        @check_if_empty(arrangements, 'The arrangement list is empty')
        def show_list():
            print(
                '\n'.join(
    f'''{x}) Destination: {country}
        Price: {destinations[country]['Price']}
        From: {destinations[country]['Dates'][0]} to {destinations[country]['Dates'][1]}'''
                    for (x, country) in enumerate(arrangements, start=1)
                )
            )

        @display_menu('Select which destination you want to add at your arrangements', destinations, 'No country has been defined in the system. No arrangement can be setup')       
        def add(arrangement):
            arrangements.append(arrangement)
            print(f'{arrangement} added')

        @display_menu('Select which destination you want to remove from your arrangements', arrangements, 'The arrangement list is empty. No arrangement to delete.', give_choice=True)
        def delete(option_chosen):
            arrangement_to_delete = arrangements[option_chosen]
            arrangements.pop(option_chosen)
            print(f'{arrangement_to_delete} deleted')
        
        actions = (
            show_country,
            show_list,
            add,
            delete,
        )
        actions[option_chosen]()

    actions = [
        destinations_menu_manager,
        arrangement_menu_manager,
    ]

    actions[option_chosen]()

main_menu_manager()
```

Maybe that will inspire to complete it